How to implement on-the-fly decryption with a Node.js video stream server?
I am working on an LMS app with Electron.js. I want to secure the video content put on that LMS while being available to played offline. So, I thought of encrypting the video files (using AES-256-CBC) and let the students download and play them through the app. Of course, they won't be able to play the videos outside the app since it's encrypted.
The issue here is that I have the video stream server working fine with normal mp4 files. However, when I try to pipe the read stream to dicipher before piping to response, it doesn't work.
I have been playing around the issue for a couple of hours. Sometimes I got WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH, others BAD_DECRYPT, ...etc.
Can you please help integrate the decryption with this video streaming server ?
Also, if you have any recommendations for this scenario better than this strategy, please do :)
This is the function initiating the video stream server.
import { createDecipheriv } from "crypto";
import { IpcMainInvokeEvent } from "electron";
import { createReadStream, statSync } from "fs";
import { createServer } from "http";

function startVideoServer(_event: IpcMainInvokeEvent, encryptedFilePath: string) {
    encryptedFilePath = "C:\\Users\\mikha\\AppData\\Roaming\\dr-youssef-nagah\\videos\\contentProtected.mp4.enc"; // Just for testing now

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const server = createServer((req, res) => {
            const decipher = createDecipheriv(
                "aes-256-cbc",
                Buffer.from("key_here_ofc", "hex"),
                Buffer.from("iv_here_too", "hex")
            );
            const input = createReadStream(encryptedFilePath);

            // Get file size
            const stats = statSync(encryptedFilePath);
            const fileSize = stats.size;
            const BLOCK_SIZE = 16; // AES block size

            // Handle range requests
            const range = req.headers.range;
            if (range) {
                const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6; // 1MB chunk size
                let start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
                let end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize - 1);

                const contentLength = end - start + 1;
                const headers = {
                    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
                    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                    "Content-Length": contentLength,
                    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
                };

                res.writeHead(206, headers);

                const stream = createReadStream(encryptedFilePath, { start, end });

                stream.pipe(res);

                // Handle stream errors properly
                stream.on("error", (error) => {
                    console.error("Stream error:", error);
                    if (!res.headersSent) {
                        res.writeHead(500, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
                    }
                    res.end();
                });

                // Ensure streams close properly when finished
                decipher.on("end", () => {
                    if (!res.writableEnded) {
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
            }

            // Handle errors
            input.on("error", (error) => {
                console.error("File read error:", error);
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end("Error reading video");
                reject(error);
            });

            decipher.on("error", (error) => {
                console.error("Decryption error:", error);
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end("Error decrypting video");
                reject(error);
            });
        });

        server.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", () => {
            const port = server.address()?.port;
            console.log(`Video server is running at http://127.0.0.1:${port}`);
            resolve(JSON.stringify({ port, server }));
        });
    });
}

export default startVideoServer;


Also, this is the function I have used to encrypt the video file.
import { createCipheriv } from "crypto";
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from "fs";

function encryptFile(filePath: string, encryptedPath: string, secretKey: string, iv: string) {
    const cipher = createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", Buffer.from(secretKey, "hex"), Buffer.from(iv, "hex"));
    const input = createReadStream(filePath);
    const output = createWriteStream(encryptedPath);

    input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);

    output.on("finish", () => {
        console.log("File encrypted successfully.");
    });
}

Appreciate any help! TIA :)

Its possibly related to the "chunk" size misaligning with the aes block size. However, I would seriously consider using HLS or MPEG-DASH for this use case. You'd have a HLS/DASH player (possibly electron has this built in like real browsers do, not sure, but there are js solutions also), and you'd chunk your video to HLS/DASH using ffmpeg or something and store/expose those chunks instead of the raw single-file source. This gets rid of the range problem entirely as the concept of HLS chunks supersedes it and I can guarantee you'll have a much easier time. HLS more popular than DASH.

HLS also has support for encryption with AES in the standard. This description is also built into the player itself, so you wouldn't even need to do it in the electron "server". HLS support is already in most browser engines, but unsure about electron. But you can also ust use https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js, which does everything you need.

@adsy I agree. Also HLS can use video files of either TS or fragmented MP4. So if they choose to use fragmented MP4 then they can just chunk the current MP4 without re-encoding the whole video (maybe only for needed keyframes).
